# libstdc++.so not found when using patchelf and alternate glibc version

Tags: c++, c, libc, libstdc++

I am working on a system with a system wide glibc 2.27 and am using pathelf to patch some executable to a customized version of glibc 2.23. The executables are compiled with a custom version of LLVM. This has been working fine on C programs, but doesn't work on C++ programs.

```
# cp Xalan_base.cc-v2 Xalan_base.cc-v2_patched
# /usr/bin/patchelf --set-interpreter /path_to/glibc-2.23_install/lib/ld-2.23.so --set-rpath /path_to/glibc-2.23_install/lib Xalan_base.cc-v2_patched
# ./Xalan_base.cc-v2_patched -v t5.xml xalanc.xsl
/path_to/Xalan_base.cc-v2_patched: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# ldd Xalan_base.cc-v2
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe9efb8000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8db1524000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8db1186000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8db0f6e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8db0b7d000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8db18ad000)
# ldd Xalan_base.cc-v2_patched
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe08b7c000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f43a5af0000)
        libm.so.6 => /path_to/glibc-2.23_install/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f43a57eb000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f43a55d3000)
        libc.so.6 => /path_to/glibc-2.23_install/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f43a5233000)
        /path_to/glibc-2.23_install/lib/ld-2.23.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f43a5e79000)
# ls -lah /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 May  8 08:51 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.25
```

As I understand, libstdc++ is a compiler library. I'm not seeing any paths to my LLVM installation here, and those I do see all appear valid.

Can you explain why this is happening? What do I need to do?

Comment: You might be better off posting this on GitHub as a patchelf issue. Also what version are you using?

Comment: You think this is a bug? I'm using patchelf 0.9, which is the latest version avaialble via Ubuntu 18.04's package repositories.

Comment: I don't know but I do think it's worth trying 0.10 if you can build a copy.

Comment: You need to use `ldd` from the custom glibc for testing, not system `ldd` (which will always use the system loader). Did you patch your glibc with multiarch path support? Upstream glibc doesn't have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you explain why this is happening?

Your `/path_to/glibc-2.23_install/lib/ld-2.23.so` does *not* look in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, and thus doesn't find `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`.

You should learn to *never* use `ldd` on your patched binary, as it will lie to you. Instead, use `/path_to/glibc-2.23_install/bin/ldd`, and it should tell you the same thing (that it can't find `libstdc++.so.6`).

> What do I need to do?

You need to arrange for `libstdc++.so.6` to be found someplace where `/path_to/glibc-2.23_install/lib/ld-2.23.so` is *actually* looking.

Something like:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /path_to/glibc-2.23_install/lib
```

should do the trick. You will likely need to repeat this for `libgcc_s.so.1` as well.

Comment: glibc-2.23_install/bin/ldd suggested all executables I tried were "not a dynamic execuatable" (not sure what that is about), but I was able to work through your resolution half-blind to symlink  libstdc++.so.6 and one other library that were missing from glibc-2.23_install.